# The superclass can call the subclass

Tags: java

In my impression,superclass can't call subclass in java.But today i have written such code,it made me puzzled...please help me!thanks

```
package CW;

public class A extends B {
    int a =100;
    public A(){
        super();
        System.out.println(a);
        a=200;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A().a);
    }
}
class B{
    public B(){
        System.out.println(((A) this).a);

    }
}
```

Is Java have such grammar?`((A) this).a`

The superclass can call the subclass.Is it allowed?

Comment: Yes Java is safer than C, but it doesn't completely prevent you from writing bad code. Yes that compiles and runs, but if you then write, `System.out.println(new B());` you'll see why casting is tricky at best and outright dangerous at worst. A bigger question is why do you think that the casting line is not or should not be valid Java?

Comment: If it weren't allowed, this wouldn't have compiled and run.

Comment: You cast it to `A`, so you can call methods from there too. This is indeed possible, but you'd better first check that `this instanceof A` is true.

Comment: Your impression was incorrect, this is legal java, (this operation is called ["casting"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) ..and totally redundant in this context/example)

Comment: Oh.I see that it is valid if superclass casting to subclass

Comment: Never edit the question to add the answer in it. [Could you please answer your own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

I think your main confusion is due to the fact that some casting errors are not identified at compile-time, but rather they are identifiable only at run-time which is why casting can be tricky at best and outright dangerous at worst. Just because the code will compile does not mean that it's safe. For instance if you put this in your main method:

```
System.out.println(new B());
```

Your program will compile but will crash.

This code:

```
((A) this).a
```

casts whatever object `this` represents to the *compiler* as an A object and is allowed since the compile will allow both up-casting and down-casting. It may or may not in fact be an A type at run-time, but the compiler will allow it due to the casting rules as formulated in [section 5.5 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1):

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>
> If S is a class type:
>
> - If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.